# Android ioctl command line can't pass io number greater than 0x7fffffff

Tags: android

it seems that there's limit on io number that Android ioctl command line can accept, does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

This limit comes from the Kernel API indirectly included from `<sys/ioctl.h>`

If you look through your NDK distribution, you will probably find the actual declarations in `<asm-generic/ioctl.h>`

An excerpt from the arm version:

```
#define _IOC_NRBITS 8
#define _IOC_TYPEBITS 8
#define _IOC_SIZEBITS 14
#define _IOC_DIRBITS 2

#define _IOC_NRMASK ((1 << _IOC_NRBITS)-1)
#define _IOC_TYPEMASK ((1 << _IOC_TYPEBITS)-1)
#define _IOC_SIZEMASK ((1 << _IOC_SIZEBITS)-1)
#define _IOC_DIRMASK ((1 << _IOC_DIRBITS)-1)
```

Ultimately it is done this way as the various arguments are bitfields which are merged together to make a single argument for the actual syscall into the kernel:

```
#define _IOC(dir,type,nr,size)   (((dir) << _IOC_DIRSHIFT) |   ((type) << _IOC_TYPESHIFT) |   ((nr) << _IOC_NRSHIFT) |   ((size) << _IOC_SIZESHIFT))
```

Note that the total is a nice 32-bit argument that will fit in a single register.